# How to change the theme of Navigation and other Bars

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I use White Action Bar and i want to use black color icons to Open Navigation drawer and more options button?

I tried using a White Action Bar but i end up getting all the icons or the buttons to be invisible in the Action bar since they are also in white color.

Kindly suggest how can i set color to the Action bar elements, as of now i want to display black icons on the Action bar with shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Voila! I have found the answer.

Just Replace the code in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Note: When u use a Light theme, it is understood that you will use only light colours in the action bar and therefore the colour of the text and icons are made dark(black).

Thank me later!